# How to deinterlace GRAY video and convert it to .avi?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avi, binary-files, grayscale

I have binary data stream from analogue camera that contains even and odd frames.

Right now I convert it to .avi with this,

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 700x220 -i data.bin -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.avi`

What I get is a 2x video duration, when even and odd frames are sequencing each other. How can deinterlace them?

UPD 1:

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 700x220 -i test1.bin -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -vf tinterlace out.avi`

This give me Doubled Vertical resolution, but the video have the same duration and it's even more slow that was before.

Comment: Are the frames like `AAAA` / `BBBB`, or `A_A_A_A_` / `_B_B_B_B`?

Comment: from camera i have AAAA_ / _BBBB but after AVID cropping I have AAAA/BBBB. Could you please help me with both cases?

Comment: @grawity, could I use tinterlace?

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -s:v 700x220 -i test1.bin -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -vf tinterlace,setpts=0.5*PTS out.avi`

Do the trick for me.